# "Cannot call method 'Kc' of null in Google graph"

Tags: json

How can I fix this bug:

```
Cannot call method 'Kc' of null in Google graph
```

JSON:

```
{
    "cols": [{
        "label": "name",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "label": "id",
        "type": "int"
    }, {
        "label": "quiz_id",
        "type": "int"
    }, {
        "label": "score",
        "type": "int"
    }],
    "rows": [{
        "c": [{
            "v": "kumar"
        }, {
            "v": "40"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }]
    }, {
        "c": [{
            "v": "kumar"
        }, {
            "v": "36"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }]
    }, {
        "c": [{
            "v": "kumar"
        }, {
            "v": "35"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }]
    }, {
        "c": [{
            "v": "kumar"
        }, {
            "v": "10"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }, {
            "v": "46"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type should be number not int.